# Remove all lines that don't match regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a range of files of a specific format. I have pasted an example [here](http://pastebin.com/GdpzW4WF).

```
----------------------------------------------
Attempting to factor n = 160000000000110400000000018963... Found a factor: 400000000000129
Time (s): 18.9561
----------------------------------------------
Attempting to factor n = 164025000000137700000000028819... Found a factor: 405000000000179
Time (s): 22.3426
----------------------------------------------
Attempting to factor n = 168100000000155800000000036051... Found a factor: 410000000000197
Time (s): 101.183
```

I would like a regular expression that I can use to capture the times, e.g. for all the lines with format "Time (s): X.Y" I want to keep X.Y on a seperate line, and throw EVERYTHING ELSE away.

I have the following expression: Time (s):\s+(\d+.\d+), which captures these. This captures the lines I need, but Notepad++ only seems to have functionality to replace with something, not save what it matches. So I can remove all those lines, which is nearly the opposite of what I want.

Any help?

Comment: You're aware that you can post well formatted code samples directly here, aren't you? Because pastebin is blocked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know Noteplad++ but its likely that you can use the result of capture groups in the replacement field. Either try

```
\1
```

or

```
$1
```

1 = first capture group. So you basically replace the whole line with \2 in your case.

Comment: I think they want to remove the lines in between as well.

Comment: Right now it looks like notepad++ only supports the \1 syntax for capture groups

Answer (score 1):

Use this on the command line:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %a in (`findstr /b "Time" 1.txt`) do @echo %a
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow next steps (Notepad++ 6.2.3):

1. Clean and mark

   Replace: `^(Time \(s\):)+ ([.\r]*)` with: `#\2`
2. Remove unmarked lines

   Replace: `^[^#]+[.\n]*` with: `(empty)`
3. Remove mark

   Replace: `^#(.*)` with: `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression to match the entire line:

```
.*\(s\)\:\s+(\d+.\d+)
```

Now you can replace this with

```
\1
```

which gives you the matched group number 1 (the only group in the above expression) that matches the time

Comment: I want to remove the lines in between as well.

Comment: Nvm I wrote a program that does it for me.

Comment: ^^ As soon as you try multi-line processing with regular expressions, it is usually easier to write a program

Comment: That's true. You cant tell regex "replace a empty line with Backspace" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your regular expression so it either matches a "Time" line and captures the time within, or matches the whole line. Then replace with the captured text, which will be blank for ignored lines.

```
Find what:     (Time \D+(\d+.\d+)|.*)
Replace with:  \2
```

This leaves you with a sequence of captured times plus blank lines, which can be removed using TextFX's Remove blank lines, or Extended Replace on "\r\n\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

Similar to MaurizioRam's answer (which lead me to figuring out this answer), you can take advantage of the "Mark" tab in the Find window.
As you probably know Ctrl+F opens a window with Find and Replace tabs. It also has tabs Find In Files, Find In Projects, and **Mark**.

Mark will let you add a special highlight (a mark) to everything your regex matches, by pressing "Mark All".

After pressing "Mark All" you can "Copy Marked Text" which will copy everything that your regex matched into your clipboard.

You can now paste this into a new file, which will give you a file with only the text your regex matched.